# Get clicked ID from parent to child element with ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, fetch-api

I'm developing an application in ReactJs and now I need to pass the clicked ID from **Main.js** page to **Sofa.js**, which will show different information depending in which ID you just clicked.
I have my ming all formatted to PHP, I wish ReactJs had a global variable like $_GET ahah. Maybe it is, I just don't now. I've been searching and don't find what I'm looking for. I'll show the code below.
Main.js code with no imports included:

```
export class Main extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            token: {},
            isLoaded: false,
            models: [],
            offset: offset,
            limit: limit
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        /* Some code not relevant to the question, for getting API token */

        fetch('url/couch-model?offset=' + offset + '&limit=' + limit, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'JWT ' + (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')).token)
            }
        }).then(res => {
            if (res.ok) {
                return res.json();
            } else {
                throw Error(res.statusText);
            }
        }).then(json => {
            this.setState({
                models: json.results,
                isLoaded: true
            }, () => { });
        })    
    }

    render() {

        const { isLoaded, models } = this.state;

        if (!isLoaded) {

            return (
                <div id="LoadText">
                    Loading...
                </div>
            )

        } else {

            return (
                <div>

                    {models.map(model =>
                        <a href={"/sofa?id=" + model.id} key={model.id}>
                            <div className="Parcelas">
                                <img src={"url" + model.image} className="ParcImage" alt="sofa" />
                                <h1>{model.name}</h1>

                                <p className="Features">{model.brand.name}</p>

                                <button className="Botao">
                                    <p className="MostraDepois">Ver Detalhes</p>
                                    <span>+</span>
                                </button>
                                <img src="../../img/points.svg" className="Decoration" alt="points" />
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    )}

                    <PageButtons offset={offset} />

                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the `<a>` inside the second return sends an ID, even though I'm not sure it's the right way. I tried writing is route-js the path like this `/sofa/:id`, but somehow, CSS inside /sofa/1 stopped working, whatever the ID was.

Now Sofa.js code, no imports and only relevant code:

```
export class Sofa extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            token: {},
            isLoaded: false,
            model: {}
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        fetch(url + '/couch-model/1{/*this show be id clicked and sent by url*/}/', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'JWT ' + (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')).token)
            }
        }).then(res => {
            if (res.ok) {
                return res.json();
            } else {
                throw Error(res.statusText);
            }
        }).then(json => {
            this.setState({
                model: json,
                isLoaded: true
            }, () => {});
        })
    }

    render() {

        const { model, isLoaded } = this.state;

        if (!isLoaded) {

            return (
                <div id="LoadText">
                    Estamos a preparar o seu sofá!
                </div>
            )

        } else {

            return (
                <div id="Esquerda">    
                    <h2>{model.area_set.map(area => area.name)}</h2>    
                    <h1>{model.name}</h1>
                    <p>Highly durable full-grain leather which is soft and has  a natural look and feel.</p>    
                    <h3>Design</h3>
                    <h4>Hexagon</h4>
                </div>
            );

        }

    }

}
```

Also, here's route.js:

```
const Routes = (props) => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/sofa/:id' component={Sofa}/>
            <Route path='/home' component={Home}/>
            <Route path='*' component={NotFound}/>            
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Routes;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you're not using (from what I can see from the example) react-router.

I really recommend you using it because it makes situations like this super easy.

Like in [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params) example

```
const ParamsExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <h2>Accounts</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/netflix">Netflix</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/zillow-group">Zillow Group</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/yahoo">Yahoo</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/modus-create">Modus Create</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <Route path="/:id" component={Child} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

And the Child component has match injected by the route.

```
const Child = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>ID: {match.params.id}</h3>
  </div>
);
```

[Here is a CodeSandbox that you can play around with](https://codesandbox.io/embed/w57kp2v18)

In your case **Sofa** is the **Child** component. You could call any API you want on componentDidMount with the id you received from the url.

Comment: I have react-router in another file called route.js, I've tried to use /:id but the CSS in that page just stopped working

Comment: @SofiaRibeiro do you see a full refresh in the page? check the view source from the page and see if you see the css file.

Comment: Yes, it does refresh. I checked now and basically it changes the path to `localhost:3000/sofa/styles.css` and the real path is `localhost:3000/styles.css`. Why is this happening?

Comment: @SofiaRibeiro instead of an a tag on Main use the Link component. You probably have your css file declared relatively like <link href="/your-file.css" /> so since you're using an a tag it actually refreshes the page and the css file searches relatively. Can you understand?

Comment: Yes, I do! Now CSS works, thanks a lot! I'll test now the rest :)

Comment: Where should it go const Child, to Sofa.js?

Comment: @SofiaRibeiro your Sofa Component is the same as the Child so you don't have do it exactly like that. Just adapt to your case

Comment: @SofiaRibeiro that is always going to happen if you have a relative path. you must declare it as an absolute path like: <link href="http://localhost:3000/mycss.css" />

Comment: I have './styles.css', but even if I put 'styles.css', happens the same

Comment: @SofiaRibeiro you should have something like 'http://localhost:3030/styles.css'. That's the absolute path. You need to adjust it to whatever port or url you have going.